# Is stream processing better than batch processing for time series Roll up/Aggregation?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, stream, batch-processing, apache-kafka-streams

**Background -**

Time series data is ingested in Apache Kafka which I store in Cassandra. As the raw data requires a lot of storage, I am attempting to aggregate the data and create hourly, daily, monthly roll-ups for reporting. There are two approaches, I can think of:

1. Stream processing:
   Use the Kafka Streams API to roll-up the data and ingest the rolled-up data in Cassandra.
2. Batch processing:
   Ingest the raw data into Cassandra and also maintain an index of newly ingested keys. Run a scheduler to fetch the keys from the index table which have been newly ingested since the last run, fetch the time series from Cassandra, roll-up and store into hourly, daily tables.

**Which method, you think is better and why?**

I tried the batch processing method. It allows me to catch up with the data, even if my roll-up series is failed/down for some time. BUT I think, it is wasting a lot of resources to provide me the reliability.

I expect the roll-up to be done without eating too many resources.

Answer (score 4):

Both solutions will be feasible. As I have little experience with Cassandra, I will only mention possibilities to solve this with Kafka Streams:

- Kafka Streams supports this use-case out of the box using windowing and aggregations:

  - https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#windowing
  - https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#streams-developer-guide-dsl-aggregating
- It also allows to deal with late arriving records:

  - https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/core-concepts.html#streams_concepts_aggregations
- With Kafka Streams you will not need to maintain a separate database besides Kafka, all your aggregations will run within your client application. Internally Kafka Streams will use RocksDB as a storage option. The aggregated results could be written to a separate output topic or queried using the interactive query feature:

  - https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html

This page includes some advanced examples:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Stream+Usage+Patterns

Comment: Worth noting that the streaming aggregations performed can be written back to a Kafka topic, and from there streamed with Kafka Connect to Cassandra (or anywhere else they're needed). You can also use KSQL in place of Kafka Streams.